# Copying a Row in Excel that match appropriate filters

Tags: excel, vba

For a project I am working on, I am attempting to copy a row from an excel spreadsheet, only if the correct criteria are met.

For example,

I need to copy a row that has the following items in them:

Fruit, Apple, True, Cell<4

I've tried using something like

```
Sub Database_RoundedRectangle1_Click()
Dim c As Range, i As Long
Dim SrchRng, strSearch

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:T60", ActiveSheet.Range("A60:T60").End(xlUp))

For Each strSearch In Array("Apple")

    Set c = SrchRng.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("Results").Paste
Next strSearch


End Sub
```

But the problem with this is that it only searches for a single criteria: Apple. I need the script to scan the whole row for all filters to be correct, then copy the row.

The script I used also only copies the row once, and does not seem to copy all rows that include Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your data is consistent i.e. you are looking for `Fruit` in one column, `Apple` in another column and likewise for `TRUE` and `<4`.
Here in the code I am looking for `Fruit in Column A`, `Apple in Column B`, `TRUE in Column C` and `<4 in Column D`. You can change column numbers as required.
I've named the sheet where data is as `Data` and the sheet to paste copied rows as `Results`

```
Sub CopyRow()
    Dim LastRowCurr As Long, LastRowResult As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currWS As Worksheet, resultWS As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange As Range

    Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")      '---> sheet where data is
    Set resultWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results") '---> sheet to paste copied rows

    lastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowResult = resultWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With currWS
        For i = 4 To lastRow
            'change column numbers in the below line as required
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Fruit" And .Cells(i, 2).Value = "Apple" And .Cells(i, 3).Value = True And .Cells(i, 4).Value < 4 Then
                .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=resultWS.Range("A" & LastRowResult)
                LastRowResult = LastRowResult + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I guess this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add another loop for the `.find` function. On your Code it only looks once for *Apples*. What you have to do is, you have to add another loop and repeat the *.find* function until you this *.find* function gives your the first match again . Try something like this:

```
Sub Database_RoundedRectangle1_Click()
Dim c As Range, i As Long
Dim SrchRng, strSearch
Dim wsResults As Worksheet
Dim firstAddress
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T60", ActiveSheet.Range("A60:T60").End(xlUp))

Set wsResults = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")

For Each strSearch In Array("Apple")


    Set c = SrchRng.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.EntireRow.Copy wsResults.UsedRange.Cells(wsResults.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
            Set c = SrchRng.FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
Next strSearch
End Sub
```